# Fastest way in numpy to get distance of n pairs

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

I have n pairs of vectors with m dimensions. I want to find the fastest way to calculate the eculidian distance of these n pairs. One way is to iterate over each pair and calculate the distance between the vectors.

Comment: Can you please show an example input and your desired output?

Comment: Try [scipy.spatial.distance.cdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) with metric set to  ‘euclidean’

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you have two arrays of coordinates and you want the element-wise euclidean distance. If so, see the following example

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8]])
>>> b = np.array([[2,4], [1,1], [8,9], [1,2]])
```

You can use `numpy.linalg.norm` along with the `axis` argument to compute an element-wise euclidean distance

```
>>> np.linalg.norm(a - b, axis=1)
array([2.23606798, 3.60555128, 4.24264069, 8.48528137])
```